# Attach MSSQL database via PHP

Tags: sql-server, drupal-6, php-5.3

I'm using Drupal 6, PHP 5.3, SQL Server 2008 R2 (connecting to MSSQL database from PHP via SQLSRV driver). Is it possible through PHP for a user to attach a new database into SQL Server?

Just to clarify the reason I need to be able to do this. My website, which displays information about train track inspections. Each train inspection for a division is stored in separate database. The user (administrator) will need to attach database every so often to update the system with more inspections. Is this possible through for the user to administer the database via PHP (i.e. attach database)?

If any of this is at all unclear, please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with PHP.

1. Upload the data file (.mdf) and log file (.ldf) to the web server.
2. Copy the data and log files to the SQL Server Data folder.
3. Call `sp_attach_db` with a SQL query.